# ListView with BaseAdapter doesn't show up If I use horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview

I tried to implement very simple `BaseAdapter`.
However the items are not displayed in the list and list rows seem to be very thin so that anything can't be shown.

My code is as bellow.

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            String[] list = new String[] {"Spot", "Stripe"};
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return list.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return list[position];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                }
                TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_left);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_right);
                text1.setText("Name");
                text2.setText(getItem(position).toString());
                return convertView;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity layout(activity_my.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

ListView item layout(item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:**

If I change `LinearLayout`'s orientation to "vertical" in item.xml the item appears.
Can somebody explain why if I set the orientation to "horizontal" the row seems to be very thin?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I set `layout_height="1dp"` in item.xml for `View` placing a space between two `TextView`. that make the row's height very thin. so I can't see anything in the ListView. If I change it as "match_parent" as same as other two `TextView`'s layout_height, it solves this problem.